# How to enable OTG in locked phone

Tags: android, mobile

I have samsung galaxy note 3 and it is locked with samsung account and i have forgot the details and failed to retrieve the id and password. my phone supports otg but it is off in settings so please tell me the way to unlock the phone or enable otg. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try rebooting you phone in safe mode first. To reboot into safe mode press and hold the power button, then long-press on *Power off* and a prompt should appear. I guess you can't connect your phone with adb when otg is disabled so I guess if the previous won't help you'll have to wipe your phone - though this is only a guess, I don't have a samsung device nor where I in this position before.

Comment: i am ready to wipe data but i need iot to unlock from samsung account

Comment: If your phone has a recovery mode you don't need to unlock the phone to wipe it. I don't know whether the note 3 has one, but you can access it like such: 1. Turn off your phone   2. Hold one of these combinations: `Power + Volume up + Home` *or* `Power + Volume down` (if one doesn't work try the other)  3. You should enter recovery mode. You navigate with volume up/down and use the power button to select something.  4. If the above doesn't work I can't help you further.